How to save (clone) a style in pgfkeys?
Is there a way to clone (deep copy) a style?
Please take a look at the example. It uses tcolorbox because it's what I need it for, but the question is acutally about pgfkeys (so I believe).
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{original/.style = {colback = pink}}
\begin{tcolorbox}[original]
    Original has pink background.
\end{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{saved/.style = {original}} %% how to save a copy?
\begin{tcolorbox}[saved]
    Saved has pink background.
\end{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{original/.style = {colback = yellow}}  % redefining orinal
\begin{tcolorbox}[saved]
    The backgound is yellow, as it should be, but
    I want saved to keep the pink background.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}

As expected, the last box has a yellow background.
My question: is there a way in pgfkeys to save in saved a copy of original, so the pink background is actually stored in the saved key instead of using \pgfkeysalso{orginal}?
I believe I need a deep copy of the key, but I coundn't find a way to do it. I read the chapter about keys (PGF Manual), but couldn't figure out any solutions.

A handler that copies the definition of one key to another is possible (like \let on a TeX level) but it won't be able to save a state of all it contains.

Here is a key handler <new>/.copy = <old> that makes <new> a copy of <old>. This is implemented by using \let on all  internal PGFKeys macros. (Not all of them are always used but that shouldn't be a problem.)
If <old> is not a code-key (i.e. a value key or not defined) an error will be raised. If <old> is not fully provided (i.e. starting with a /) the current namespace is added.
This means that \tcbset{saved/.copy = original} is the same as \tcbset{saved/.copy = /tcb/original}.
Code
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\makeatletter
\def\pgfkeys@letlet#1#2#3{\expandafter\let\csname pgfk@#1/#3\expandafter\endcsname\csname pgfk@#2/#3\endcsname}
\pgfkeys{
  /handlers/.copy/.code={% <key 1>/.copy = <key 2> makes <key 1> a copy of <key 2>
    \begingroup
      \def\pgfkeyscurrentkey{#1}%
      \pgfkeys@add@path@as@needed
      \edef\pgfkeys@temp{\endgroup\def\noexpand\pgfkeys@temp{\pgfkeyscurrentkey}}%
    \pgfkeys@temp
    \pgfkeysifdefined{\pgfkeys@temp/.@cmd}{%
      \pgfkeys@letlet{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{\pgfkeys@temp}{.@cmd}%
      \pgfkeys@letlet{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{\pgfkeys@temp}{.@args}%
      \pgfkeys@letlet{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{\pgfkeys@temp}{.@def}%
      \pgfkeys@letlet{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{\pgfkeys@temp}{.@body}%
      \pgfkeys@letlet{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{\pgfkeys@temp}{.@@body}%
    }{%
      \pgfkeys@error{The key '\pgfkeys@temp' is not a code-key.}%
    }%
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tcbset{original/.style = {colback = pink}}
\begin{tcolorbox}[original]
  Original has pink background.
\end{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{saved/.copy = original} %% how to save a copy?
\begin{tcolorbox}[saved]
  Saved has pink background.
\end{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{original/.style = {colback = yellow}}  % redefining orinal
\begin{tcolorbox}[saved]
  The backgound is yellow, as it should be, but
  I want saved to keep the pink background.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}


Keys that are bot a code-key and a value-key will not be copied properly.
